# Can we add a formula in a DataTable's export to Excel?

Tags: excel, datatables, export-to-excel

I need to add a formula to an Excel sheet that is exported from DataTables. I am trying the code written below

```
{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' },
            
    customizeData: function(data){
      //Add a row.
      var desc = [
        ['','TOTAL','','','=sum(E1:E15)']
      ];
      // data.body.unshift(data.header);
      for (var i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
        data.body.push(desc[i]);
      };
  }
},
```

But it adds the formula as text and it works as a formula only after key focus on that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach causes the Excel (xlsx) file to store the formula as a string (as you have noted).

Specifically, the DataTables Excel export stores it as an "inline string" using the `t="inlineStr"` attribute. This needs to be changed to `t="str"` for a formula. The actual text of the formula needs to be contained in a `<f>` tag, also ([see the OpenXML reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-formulas)).

The following code takes the raw DataTables data provided by the `customizeData()` function, and modifies the way it is stored in Excel:

*Note - this code uses my sample data, shown below in the full demo.*

```js
customize: function ( xlsx ) {
  var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
  var cell = $('row c[r=D8]', sheet);
  $(cell).attr( 't', 'str' );
  $(cell).append('<f>' + $('is t', cell).text() + '</f>');
  $('is', cell).remove();
}
```

The above code uses jQuery to manipulate the XML used for storing the Excel structures.

I have simplified the logic to hard-code the cell `D8` where the formula is placed. You may have to alter that for your specific data needs.

Before the `customize` function is used, the cell content would have been stored as a plain inline string:

```xml
<c t="inlineStr" r="D8">
    <is>
       <t xml:space="preserve">=sum(D3:D7)</t>
    </is>
 </c>
```

After the `customize` function is added, the cell content is stored as a formula:

```xml
<c t="str" r="D8">
    <f>=sum(D3:D7)</f>
</c>
```

---

The demo code (I don't think this actually runs in a Stack Snippet - the Excel file cannot be downloaded here):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Brftip',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'excelHtml5',

      customizeData: function(data) {
        var desc = [
          ['', 'TOTAL', '', '=sum(D3:D7)']
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
          data.body.push(desc[i]);
        };
      },

      customize: function(xlsx) {    
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        var cell = $('row c[r=D8]', sheet);
        console.log(cell);
        $(cell).attr('t', 'str');
        console.log(cell);
        $(cell).append('<f>' + $('is t', cell).text() + '</f>');
        console.log(cell);
        $('is', cell).remove();
        console.log(cell);
      }

    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/css/buttons.dataTables.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.3/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The `customizeData` function (which you already have) operates on the raw data provided by DataTables.

Then the new `customize` function operates on the target Excel file (the underlying OpenXML structures), to convert a string to a formula.

The end result (in edit mode):

[image]

---

**Final Notes**

When I run this in a web page, the downloaded Excel file is automatically opened in read-only mode (as a safeguard). At this point, you cannot see the formula.

You have to choose to open the file for editing for the formula to be visible.

[image]

That is a safety feature of the version of Excel I am using.

You can adjust these settings if needed (but I recommend keeping them as they are, for security):

[image]

Comment: Can we do sum of rows ?

Comment: I expect so. Have you tried?